# Change custom object's label

Tags: custom-object

What are the known repercussion of changing a custom object's 'Label'?

On Object edit page Salesforce has the message, "Be careful when changing the name or label as it may affect existing integrations and merge templates." Not trying to change the 'Object Name' but only 'Label'

Thank you in advance for your response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most of scenario changing label should not break any code (I have not seen breaking code and integration yet). Changing label means it will changle everywhere like Tab, Reports, Record etc.

However if you are using label in your code somewhere or in any integration (Sometimes label refered in dynamic apex), it may cause break.

Comment: Thanks Jitendra. Running the eclipse search right now to check to confirm the object's label is not referred. to.